# How to use replace holder in json with python code?

Tags: python, json, xml

I have a question to update json script with replace holder with python.

The code:

```
json_str = '''
<Execute xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
                  <Statement>
                  <DatabaseName>{database}</DatabaseName>
                    <![CDATA[
                    {{
                      \"create\": {{
                        \"object\": {{
                          \"database\":\"{{{database}}}\"
                        }}
                        }}
                      }}
                    ]]>
                </Statement>
        </Execute>'''

replaced_str = json_str.format(database='testDB')
print(replaced_str)
```

The output is:

```
 <Execute xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
                                  <Statement>
                                  <DatabaseName>testDB</DatabaseName>
                                        <![CDATA[
                                        {
                      "create": {
                        "object": {
                          "database":"{testDB}"
                        }
                        }
                      }
                                        ]]>
                                </Statement>
                </Execute>
```

Anybody is familiar about how to change the curly brace escape to get the expected output from:
"database":"{testDB}" to  "database":"testDB" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove two of `{}`: From `{{{database}}}` to `{database}`:

```
json_str = '''
        <Execute xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
            <Command>
                  <Statement>
                  <DatabaseName>{database}</DatabaseName>
                    <![CDATA[
                    {{
                      \"create\": {{
                        \"object\": {{
                          \"database\":\"{database}\"
                        }}
                        }}
                      }}
                    ]]>
                </Statement>
            </Command>
            <Properties />
        </Execute>'''
replaced_str = json_str.format(database='testDB')
print(replaced_str)
```

Output:

```
        <Execute xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
            <Command>
                  <Statement>
                  <DatabaseName>testDB</DatabaseName>
                    <![CDATA[
                    {
                      "create": {
                        "object": {
                          "database":"testDB"
                        }
                        }
                      }
                    ]]>
                </Statement>
            </Command>
            <Properties />
        </Execute>
```

In fact, you can also replace `\"` by `"`.